# Missing dependency in graphql-maven-plugin generated code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql

I have created a very simple graphql server using spring-boot which just has the methods findById and list for an object and I want to create a junit test for these commands and as I wanted to try code generation to create a client I could use in that test.

The issue is that when I generate the code I get the error that: `package org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client does not exist`

I have `spring-boot-starter-webflux` as dependency in my `pom.xml` and when I use for example the `WebClient` from the package above in my code it's working fine, but in the generated `GraphQLMavenPluginAutoConfiguration` the package is not found.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.graphql-java-generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>graphql-java-client-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    [..]
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateClientCode</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schemaFileFolder>src/main/resources/graphql</schemaFileFolder>
              <packageName>my.test.graphql.generated</packageName>

              <generateDeprecatedRequestResponse>false</generateDeprecatedRequestResponse>
              <separateUtilityClasses>true</separateUtilityClasses>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The error occures when executing `mvn clean install`